# sockets.io using eronious websocket address

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, sockets, express

So for some reason the web socket address is the head of my html in URL form and on load socket.io fails to connect. In the JavaScript console I get this output;

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:3000/socket.io/1/websocket/%3C!DOCTYPE%20html%3E%3Chtml%20ng-app=%22myApp%22%3E%3Chead%3E%3Cmeta%20charset=%22utf8%22%3E%3Cbase%20href=%22/%22%3E%3Ctitle%3EOnSite%3C/title%3E%3Clink%20rel=%22stylesheet%22%20href=%22/css/app.css%22%3E%3Clink%20rel=%22stylesheet%22%20href=%22/css/bootstrap.min.css%22%3E%3Clink%20rel=%22stylesheet%22%20href=%22/css/pixel-admin.min.css%22%3E%3Clink%20rel=%22stylesheet%22%20href=%22/css/widgets.min.css%22%3E%3Clink%20rel=%22stylesheet%22%20href=%22/css/rtl.min.cs...app.js%22%3E%3C/script%3E%3Cscript%20src=%22js/services.js%22%3E%3C/script%3E%3Cscript%20src=%22js/controllers.js%22%3E%3C/script%3E%3Cscript%20src=%22js/filters.js%22%3E%3C/script%3E%3Cscript%20src=%22js/directives.js%22%3E%3C/script%3E%3Cscript%20src=%22js/lib/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js%22%3E%3C/script%3E%3Cscript%20src=%22js/lib/bootstrap/pixel-admin.min.js%22%3E%3C/script%3E%3Cscript%20src=%22js/lib/jQuery/jQuery_v2.1.1.js%22%3E%3C/script%3E%3Cscript%20src=%22js/mytest.js%22%3E%3C/script%3E%3C/html%3E' failed: Connection closed before receiving a handshake response 
mytest.js:6(anonymous function) mytest.js:6j jQuery_v2.1.1.js:2k.fireWith jQuery_v2.1.1.js:2x jQuery_v2.1.1.js:4(anonymous function)
```

I figured this must have been because of my node setup so I rebuilt the app.js but had the same result each time, but after some research I found someone who solved [a very similar bug](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails.io.js/issues/17) but I'm not sure how I can apply their fix to my code.
app.js;

```
// ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: //
// ::             Module dependencies           :: //
// ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: //
var express         = require('express');
var server          = require('http').Server(app);
var io              = require('socket.io')(server);
var methodOverride  = require('method-override');
var morgan          = require('morgan');
var cookieParser    = require('cookie-parser');
var path            = require('path');
var bodyParser      = require('body-parser');
var mongoose        = require('mongoose');
var passport        = require('passport');
var bcrypt          = require('bcrypt');
var randomstring    = require("randomstring");
var moment          = require("moment");

var api = require('./routes/api');
var app             = express();



// ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: //
// ::               Configuration               :: //
// ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: //

// All environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(methodOverride());
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Database
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/onsite');

var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function callback () {});

require('./models/History');
require('./models/Person');
require('./models/Zone');
require('./models/User');

// Passport Setup
require('./config/passport')(app, passport, db, mongoose);

var env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';

// ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: //
// ::                  socket.io                :: //
// ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: //

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    io.emit('socket', "hello");
});
io.on('api', function(socket){
    io.emit('socket', "server message");
});



// ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: //
// ::               Start Server                :: //
// ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: //

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function () {
  console.log('\nServer listing on http://localhost:' + app.get('port'));
  console.log('\t-> To stop server running: CONTROL + C ')
});
```

Bottom of my body where I include `socket.io.min.js`;

```
</div><script src="js/lib/socket.io.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var socket = io.connect();
</script>
<script src="js/lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/services.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
<script src="js/filters.js"></script>
<script src="js/directives.js"></script>
<script src="js/lib/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/lib/bootstrap/pixel-admin.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/lib/jQuery/jQuery_v2.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="js/mytest.js"></script>
```

Comment: The error message makes it look like the URL you're trying to connect to is messed up.  Where is that declared?  Can you show that code?

Comment: Also, it might help if you showed the relevant portion of the code as the browser sees it rather than in template form.

Comment: Which version of express?  My understanding is that this works differently in Express 3 vs. Express 4.

Comment: At least this line is wrong : `script(src='js/lib/socket.io.min.js')` you should include the socket client from your server, ie: `script(src='http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js')`. Though your issue seems deeper than that. Can you show us the routes of your app?

Comment: @jfriend00 
1. I'm testing on `http://localhost:3000/` if thats what you are asking, I don't know where I would set the websockets address apart from `var socket = io.connect();` and I don't think I should need to. 
2. Updated post.
3. I'm using `"express": "~4.1.1"`

Comment: In Express 4, I set up socket.io on my server differently like this: `var app = express(); var server = app.listen(8081); var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);`

Comment: @xShirase isn't `script(src='js/lib/socket.io.min.js')` and `script(src='http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js')` equivalent, just one it is a relative path and the other is an absolute path with a different directory?

Comment: Nope, the localhost:3000... is the file located in your node_modules

Comment: I have changed `script(src='js/lib/socket.io.min.js')` to `script(src='http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js')` and I have a different bug now, I get thousands of get requests; `GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1412486327064-0 200 36.028 ms - 1552
GET /js/lib/socket.io.min.js?_=1412486327107 200 2.517 ms - 44814
GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1412486327174-1 200 36.062 ms - 1552
GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1412486327301-2 200 20.293 ms - 1552
GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1412486327327-3 200 21.198 ms - 1552
....
`

Comment: Just realised I'm still including /js/lib/socket.io.min.js so I removed it and I have the same bug. I also had to make a `socket.io/` dir in my public directory from what @xShirase said I dont think I should have done that?